# Am I understanding Eccentricity, Radius and Diameter right?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

Eccentricity, radius and diameter as defined in "Graph Theory and Complex Networks: An Introduction" (van Steen, 2010):

> Consider a connected graph G and let d(u,v) denote the distance
>   between vertices u and v. The eccentricity e(u) of a vertex u in G is
>   deﬁned as max{d(u,v)|v € V(G)}. The radius rad(G) is equal to
>   min{e(u)|u € V(G)}. Finally, the diameter of G is the maximal shortest
>   path between any two vertices: diam(G) = max{d(u,v)|u,v € V(G)}.

I'm using the Euro sign € where I mean "within set"

Does this mean that "*radius of G*" = "*smallest eccentricity*" and "*diameter of G*" = "*largest eccentricity*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed they do. As is stated in the book, $\DeclareMathOperator{\rad}{rad}\rad(G)=\min{\{e(u)|u\in V(G)\}}$, so by definition, "radius of $G$" = "smallest eccentricity." As for the diameter,

$\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}\diam(G)=\max{\{d(u,v)|u,v\in V(G)\}}\\=\max\{\max{\{d(u,v)|u,v\in V(G)\}|u\in V(G)}\}\\=\max\{e(u)|u\in V(G)\},$

so "diameter of $G$" = "largest eccentricity."